# how to run the start function in a thread

Tags: python, multithreading

i was wondering how i could run the start function of this .py program in a thread

Program:

```
import time

jobs = []
verbose = False

def initialize(ver):
    global verbose
    verbose = ver

def addJob(function, timeout, args = None):
    global verbose
    """
    Adds job to the cron list
    :param func function: Function to call
    :param int timeout: Call after every x seconds
    """
    jobs.append([function, timeout, args])
    if(verbose):
        print("Cron Job [ {0}('{1}') ] Registered [Running Every {2}s]".format(function.__name__, args, timeout))

def start():
    """
    Start the cron job counter
    This is a thread blocking function
    """
    seconds = 1
    while 1:

        for job in jobs:
            if seconds % job[1] == 0:
                if job[2] == None:
                    job[0]()
                else:
                    job[0](job[2])

        time.sleep(1)
        seconds += 1
```

This is the code i came up with that could possibly work

```
import time
import threading

jobs = []
verbose = False

def initialize(ver):
    global verbose
    verbose = ver

def addJob(function, timeout, args=None):
    global verbose
    """
    Adds job to the cron list
    :param function: Function to call
    :param timeout: Call after every x seconds
    """
    jobs.append([function, timeout, args])
    if verbose:
        print("Cron Job [ {0}('{1}') ] Registered [Running Every {2}s]".format(function.__name__, args, timeout))

def start():
    """
    Start the cron job counter
    This is a thread-blocking function
    """
    seconds = 1
    while True:
        for job in jobs:
            if seconds % job[1] == 0:
                if job[2] is None:
                    job[0]()
                else:
                    job[0](job[2])
        time.sleep(1)
        seconds += 1

def run_in_thread():
    """
    Creates a new thread and starts the cron job counter in that thread
    """
    thread = threading.Thread(target=start)
    thread.start()

# Example usage
initialize(True)

def my_function():
    print("Running cron job")

addJob(my_function, 5)  # Add a job that runs every 5 seconds

# Start the cron job in a separate thread
run_in_thread()
```

I added a new function run_in_thread() that creates a new thread and starts the start() function in that thread. This allows the start() function to run concurrently with the main program.

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. Does it work?

Comment: Do you do anything else in the program? As is, I'm not seeing why you need a thread, because the *main* thread isn't doing anything after launching the other thread.

Comment: Re, "This...could possibly work." Well, _does_ it work? If it doesn't work, then what does it do instead that is puzzling you? If it does work, then what is your question? If you want to know what other people think of the style and quality of _working_ code, consider asking at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/